# Absolute or Relative URL if my website may not be at the root folder?

Tags: html, url, relative-path, absolute-path

I am developing a website on a web server which can be accessed by 2 URL: `mywebsite.example.com` or `example.com/mywebsite`. For example, when I access `mywebsite.example.com/images/abc.jpg` and `example.com/mywebsite/images/abc.jpg`, I get the same picture.

The problem is, I have many links inside my website, and I am not sure should I use an absolute or relative path.

From another question
[Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)
I found someone suggesting using URL relative to root (like /images/abc.jpg), however when I access the website using example.com/mywebsite, every link just break.

For relative paths, I found it hard to manage since webpages are in different folders, but using the same template which contains some links. It means I have to manually set some links as `../` and some as `./`.

I have also tried using `<base>` tag however it messes up with anchor. Even if I try to include the full path before the `#` symbol, some jQuery libraries does not function properly since they get the value inside the attribute `href` directly, but not extracting the part after `#`.

Would there be any better practice or suggestion?

Comment: I suggest picking one URL and sticking with it. [Redirect](https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection) other URLs to the one you choose and use relative paths for links and images. See [canonicalization](https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization).

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to do redirecting as I am not the owner of the server and does not have permission on that. If I am able to stick with one of the URL I'd have done so already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use relative urls, and concentrate your searchs on how to use relative urls in templates, that would be resolved relatively to the final page.

I don't know the technology you are using for templating, but I see two common solutions :

- declare a "relative path" variable in the template, and then override it in the different pages, with the new relative path. Use this relative path as a prefix for all urls
- delegate urls construction to a service that would know the final page. Somethinkg like `resolveUrl(..)`